# Getting contract binary using web3j

Tags: blockchain, web3j, java

I'm using [web3J library](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/web3j/latest/web3j.pdf) in my java app.
I got an address of a deployed contract and would like to get it's binary or abi from the blockchain using my java app, how can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is how to read the bytecode using web3j:

```
    EthGetCode ethGetCode = web3j.ethGetCode("0x248b73642eab74b3cfb32f5ecd0ff1a12a5e6a4f",DefaultBlockParameterName.LATEST).send();
    String s=ethGetCode.getCode();
    System.out.println(s);
```

for the ABI you can't read it from the blockchain but you have to generate it from the code if you have it.

Comment: Thanks Badr. Do you happen to know how can I get the contract creator address via web3j?